# G++ narrowing conversions with C++98

Tags: c++, linux, g++

I have a C++98 project on linux with g++ 4.7.3 and I'm getting lots of warnings about "narrowing conversion is ill-formed in C++11"

How come? I'm not even using C++11

Comment: Some code that exhibits the warning would help. And double check your compiler options.

Comment: If you included an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) along with the compilation command line and output, that would help make the question more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those warnings are "this is valid now, but won't be valid in the future" warnings. They're specifically designed for code that is valid C++98, that won't cause a compilation error in C++98 mode, but would cause problems if you intend to switch to C++11 in the future. They don't get enabled by default, but do by `-Wall`. If you're really sure that that isn't going to happen, you can change `-Wall` to `-Wall -Wno-c++11-compat`

Example code:

```
unsigned u[] = {-1};
```

```
$ g++ -c test.cc -ansi -pedantic
$ g++ -c test.cc -ansi -pedantic -Wall
test.cc:1:19: warning: narrowing conversion of ‘-1’ from ‘int’ to ‘unsigned int’ inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]
 unsigned u[] = {-1};
                   ^
$ g++ -c test.cc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wno-c++11-compat
```